# Setting up routes for url shortener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I"m trying to create a rails app that functions as a url shortener. I'm having trouble configuring the routes. How can I allow for the user visit my site and be redirected to the site base on the url they enter. I.E. mysite.com/any_random_url.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/about'
  get 'home/:id' => 'home#show'    

  root 'home#show/:id'
  ..
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def about
  end

  def show
    url = params[:id]
    @url = ShortUrl.where(["url = ?", url]).first
    if @url.nil?
      return redirect_to action: 'index', status: 307
    else
      return redirect_to @url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to have multiple slashes you'll need something like:

```
get '*id', to: 'home#show'
```

If you only want a single subpath (i.e. /23af1) it's probably better to use:

```
get ':id', to: 'home#show'
```

You can find more info in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments)